# Installing mongodb for php & composer error

Tags: php, mongodb, xampp, composer-php

I am currently using xampp for PHP. I have downloaded *php_mongodb-1.13.0-8.1-ts-vs16-x64* in my system and also installed *xampp-windows-x64-8.2.0-0-VS16* in my system. In order to configure PHP for mongoDB, I have downloaded *php_mongo.dll* and pasted the .dll file in the '../php/ext' directory and also added extension=php_mongo.dll in the php.ini file.

Now when I try to install composer, it shows that Composer setup cannot continue with your current settings and throws the following errors.

```
The PHP exe file you specified did not run correctly:
E:\Project\XAMMP\php\php.exe

The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: E:\Project\XAMMP\php\php.ini

A setting in your php.ini could be causing the problem: Either the 'extension_dir' value is incorrect or a dll does not exist.

Program Output:
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: mongodb: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20210902
PHP    compiled with module API=20220829
These options need to match
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: "A setting in your php.ini could be causing the problem: Either the 'extension_dir' value is incorrect or a dll does not exist." - what did you try to resolve that problem?

Comment: I downgraded my PHP version to 8.1 , and it solved the issue.